# PagingDataAdapter stops loading after fragment is removed and added back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-paging

I am presenting a `PagingSource` returned by Room ORM on a PagingDataAdapter.

The `RecyclerView` is present on a Fragment -- I have two such fragments. When they are switched, they stop loading the items on next page and only placehodlers are shown on scrolling.

Please view these screen captures if it isn't clear what I mean--

- [When I scroll without switching fragments, all the items are loaded](https://files.catbox.moe/wmsrrl.mp4)
- [When I switch Fragments before scrolling all the way down, the adapter stops loading new items](https://files.catbox.moe/arwzps.mp4)

**Relevant pieces of code (please ask if you would like to see some other part/file) -**

The Fragment:

```kotlin
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private val recyclerAdapter = CustomersAdapter(this)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
    recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.customersFlow.collectLatest { pagingData ->
           recyclerAdapter.submitData(pagingData)
        }
    }
}
```

View model-

```kotlin
class CustomersListViewModel(application: Application, private val debtOnly: Boolean): ViewModel() {

    private val db = AppDatabase.instance(application)
    private val customersDao = db.customersDao()

    val customersFlow = Pager(PagingConfig(20)) {
        if (debtOnly)
            customersDao.getAllDebt()
        else
            customersDao.getAll()
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Comment: Let me know the TestApp source code, I can help with your issue.

Comment: @DucThang Thanks for willingness to help! I pushed the source code here please check:  https://github.com/quanta-kt/SMJ-App/tree/master

Comment: Ok, @Quanta let me check!

Comment: I have answered your question, please check if it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I went through your code, I found the problem `FragmentTransaction.replace` function and `flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`
When the activity calls the `replace` fragment function, the CustomerFragment will be destroyed and its ViewModel will also be destroyed (the `viewModel.onCleared()` is triggered) so this time `cachedIn(viewModelScope)` is also invalid.

I have 3 solutions for you

**Solution 1: Remove `.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`**

Note that this is only a temporary solution and is not recommended.
Because of this, instances of fragments still exist on the activity but the fragments had destroyed (memory is still leaking).

**Solution 2: Instead of using the `FragmentTransaction.replace` function in the Main activity, use the `FragmentTransaction.add` function**:

It does not leak memory and can still use the `cachedIn` function. Should be used when the activity has few fragments and the fragment's view is not too complicated.

```
private fun switchNavigationFragment(navId: Int) {
    when (navId) {
        R.id.nav_customers -> {
            switchFragment(allCustomersFragment, "Customer")
        }
        R.id.nav_debt -> {
            switchFragment(debtCustomersFragment, "DebtCustomer")
        }
    }
}

private fun switchFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String) {
    val existingFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
            if (it.isVisible && it != fragment) {
                hide(it)
            }
        }
        if (existingFragment != fragment) {
            add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
                .disallowAddToBackStack()
        } else {
            show(fragment)
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 3: Using with Navigation Component Jetpack**

This is the safest solution.
It can be created using Android Studio's template or some of the following articles.

[Navigation UI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

[A safer way to collect flows](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda)

I tried solution 1 and 2 and here is the result:

[image: The Result]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I'll definitely try it out next morning, tired and down right now

Comment: Neat. Can you please also point out in short why `disallowAddToBackStack()` call is required?

Comment: Actually, without needing it, it still works properly, here is my code from an old project. You can see more at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#disallowAddToBackStack().

Comment: I want to prevent some careless calling it to add to the fragment stack, when pressing back it will not return to the previous fragment but will exit the app.